# Flutter SliverAppBar, Collapse background to fill the leading space

Tags: flutter, charts, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver, sliverappbar

I want to use create a sliver list view with a `SliverAppBar` such that when I scroll up the list, the icon inside the body shrinks to take place in the `leading` space of appBar.

The images here show something that I want to achieve. When I scroll up, the chart should move up and slide beside the title. (Something similar to Hero widget)

Till now, I tried `SliverAppBar`, but was not able to succeed. I am happy to use some other widget to achieve this. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried with this?

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  //Variables needed to adapt FlexibleSpaceBar text color (title)
  ScrollController _scrollController;
  bool lastStatus = true;
  double height = 200;

  void _scrollListener() {
    if (_isShrink != lastStatus) {
      setState(() {
        lastStatus = _isShrink;
      });
    }
  }

  bool get _isShrink {
    return _scrollController.hasClients &&
        _scrollController.offset > (height - kToolbarHeight);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _scrollController = ScrollController()..addListener(_scrollListener);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.removeListener(_scrollListener);
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: height,
              floating: false,
              pinned: true,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                centerTitle: true,
                title: _isShrink
                    ? Row(
                        children: [
                          //Replace container with your chart
                          // Here you can also use SizedBox in order to define a chart size
                          Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                              width: 30,
                              height: 30,
                              color: Colors.yellow),
                          Text('A little long title'),
                        ],
                      )
                    : SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                'A little long title',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              ),
                              //Replace container with your chart
                              Container(
                                height: 80,
                                color: Colors.yellow,
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text('Your chart here'),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ]),
                      ),
              ),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 100,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
              height: 40,
              child: Text(index.toString()),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: solution_gif]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done with SliverAppBar. You should search in Pub.dev for packages may this help you [fluent_appbar](https://pub.dev/packages/fluent_appbar)